# Typeorm, MongoDB and TypeGraphQL - Populate - Lookup

Tags: mongodb, typescript, graphql, nosql, typeorm

I am working with Typeorm and MongoDB. I have a UserAlert entity that saves the _id of another User entity as a field. My question is how you can get the information of the entity that that _id refers to. It would be something similar to **populate** in mongoose.

Example:

User:

```
@Entity({ name: 'Users' })
export default class User extends BaseEntity {
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    _id!: ObjectID;

    @Column('string')
    firstName!: string;

    @Column('string')
    lastName!: string;

    @Column('string')
    phoneNumber!: string;

}
```

User Alert:

```
@Entity({ name: 'UserAlerts' })
export default class UserAlert extends BaseEntity {
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    _id!: ObjectID;

    //REFERENCE
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    userId!: ObjectID;

    @Column('date')
    date!: Date;
}
```

Result: User Alert

```
{
   "_id":"asdbfsdf32112312dasdas",
   "date":"15/09/2021",
   "User":{
       "_id":"asdas6d5412634123654",
       "firstName":"Jorge",
       "lastName":"Mamani",
       "phoneNumber":"465465"
   }
}
```

How would I have to present the data in Type GraphQL?

Comment: search for 'typeorm graphql relations' [tutorials] - in graphql we have **resolvers** for fields, relations, everything ... all data is 'polulated' when required using resolvers

Comment: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/9494